# BackgroundService is blocking completion of WebApplicationFactory.CreateClient in integration test

Tags: c#, integration-testing, asp.net-core-3.1, specflow

We are using SpecFlow to write integration tests for a .net-core-3.1 WebApplication. Our web-app includes a BackgroundService used to subscribe to Kafka. The presence of this BackgroundService prevents the WebApplicationFactory.CreateClient method from completing. I've read about people experiencing a similar problem in testing environments with limited resources, but this is happening for us on modern laptops.

The constructor for our test class:

```
public PocServiceSteps(ScenarioContext context)
{
    _context = context;

    _factory = new WebApplicationFactory<Startup>()
    .WithWebHostBuilder(builder => builder.ConfigureServices(services =>
    {
        // setup any required services changes here
    }));

    // this method never completes
    _client = _factory.CreateClient(
        new WebApplicationFactoryClientOptions
        {
            BaseAddress = new Uri($"http://localhost:5000/")
        }
    );
}
```

One thing we have tried is to override WebApplicationFactory per https://www.strathweb.com/2021/05/the-curious-case-of-asp-net-core-integration-test-deadlock/, but this does not resolve the problem:

```
private class AsyncFriendlyWebApplicationFactory<T> : WebApplicationFactory<T> where T : class
{
    protected override IHost CreateHost(IHostBuilder builder)
    {
        var host = builder.Build();
        Task.Run(() => host.StartAsync()).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
        return host;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include what it means when you say *"The presence of this BackgroundService prevents the WebApplicationFactory.CreateClient method from completing."* Are you getting an exception? If so, what is the error message and stack trace. If you are not getting an error, what exactly is the behavior? Does the method just hang and never return?

Comment: I switched over to TestServer directly and the issue went away. I know not perfect but works for me.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't need the Background-Service for your test, you can just remove it:

```cs
var factory = new WebApplicationFactory<Startup>()
    .WithWebHostBuilder(builder =>
        builder.ConfigureTestServices(s =>
        {
            var descriptor = s.SingleOrDefault(
                d => d.ImplementationType ==
                     typeof(MyBackgroundService));

            s.Remove(descriptor);
        })
    );
```

If you registered your service in the Startup.cs like this:

```cs
builder.Services.AddHostedService<MyBackgroundService>();
```